# Multi objective convex optimization using genetic algorithm or cvx tool

Tags: algorithm, matlab

I have solved a single objective convex optimization problem (actually related to reducing interference reduction) using cvx package with MATLAB. Now I want to extend the problem to multi objective one. What are the pros-cons of solving it using genetic algorithm in comparison to cvx package? I haven't read anything about genetic algorithms and it came about by searching net for multiobjective optimization.

Comment: I don't think SO is the place for such questions, you should try [Computer Science SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/). But are you sure that CVX can solve multiobjective LP?

Comment: You have to convert a multi-objective problem into a single objective by minimizing some function (eg. linear combination) of the multiple objectives.

A multi objective minimization problem on its own isn't a well defined mathematical problem. Eg. let `f(x) = x` and `g(x) = -x`. It's a non-sensical problem to say "minimize `f(x)` and `g(x)` such that `x` in `[0, 10]`"

Answer (score 1):

The optimization algorithms based on derivatives (or gradients) including convex optimization algorithm essentially try to find a local minimum. The pros and cons are as follows.

Pros:
1. It can be extremely fast since it only tries to follow the path given by derivative.
2. Sometimes, it achieves the global minimum (e.g., the problem is convex).

Cons:
1. When the problem is highly nonlinear and non-convex, the solution depends on initial point, hence there is high probability that the solution achieved is far from the global optimum.
2. It's not quite for multi-objective optimization problem.

Because of the disadvantages described above, for multi-objective optimization, we generally use evolutionary algorithm. Genetic algorithms belong to evolutionary algorithm.

Evolutionary algorithms developed for multi-objective optimization problems are fundamentally different from the gradient-based algorithms. They are population-based, i.e., maintain multiple solutions (hundreds or thousands of them) where as the latter ones maintain only one solution.

NSGA-II is an example: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/996017, https://mae.ufl.edu/haftka/stropt/Lectures/multi_objective_GA.pdf, https://web.njit.edu/~horacio/Math451H/download/Seshadri_NSGA-II.pdf

The purpose of the multi-objective optimization is find the Pareto surface (or optimal trade-off surface). Since the *surface* consists of multiple points, population-based evolutionary algorithms suit well.

(You can solve a series of single objective optimization problems using gradient-based algorithms, but unless the feasible set is convex, it cannot find them accurately.)